# How can I create Mon_Year column after multiple excel files read based on filename in R?

Tags: r

I have excel files that are named as follows:

```
Test Sample October 2023.xlsx
Test Sample November 2023.xlsx
Test Sample December 2023.xlsx
Test Sample January 2024.xlsx
Test Sample February 2024.xlsx
Test Sample march 2024.xlsx
```

I want a new mon_year column added to each row as follows after excel file read:

```
Oct 2023
Nov 2023
Dec 2023
Jan 2023
Feb 2023
Mar 2023
```

I got it to read multiple files using following code. Not sure how to add new column.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls", path = "wd", recursive = TRUE, 
                    full.names = TRUE, all.files = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

lst_of_frames <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel)
```

Comment: I presume this approach could be adapted for file names instead of sheet names: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/readxl-workflows.html#iterate-over-multiple-worksheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: You could take `your_files |>  stringr::str_remove("Test Sample ") |> string::str_remove(".xlsx") |> lubridate::my() |> format("%b %Y")` to get the date labels you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to approach to add new column into each file.

```
# Load required libraries
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

# Set your working directory or provide the full path
setwd("C:/Users/murad.khalilov/Downloads/TEST/")

# Get a list of Excel files
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

# Read each Excel file into a list of data frames
lst_of_frames <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel)

# Function to add a new column with year-month information to a data frame
add_year_month_column <- function(df, file_name) {
  # Extract month and year from the file name
  base_name <- basename(file_name)
  file_month_year <- strsplit(base_name, " ")[[1]][3:4]
  
  # Remove the "xlsx" extension from file_month_year[2]

  file_year <- tolower(sub(".xlsx$", "", file_month_year[2], ignore.case = TRUE))
  
  # Convert month and year to proper case and create a new column
  df$`Year-Month` <- paste0(str_to_title(file_month_year[1]), " ", file_year)
  
  return(df)
}

# Apply the function to each data frame in the list
lst_of_frames <- Map(add_year_month_column, lst_of_frames, files)

# Now, lst_of_frames contains the modified data frames with the new column

# Print the first few rows of each modified data frame
lapply(lst_of_frames, head)
```

Comment: Thanks Murad! Is it possible to sort data based on newly added column 'Year-Month'? I created new data frame using the list of frames and tried this. It didn't yield the result.                 data_frame<-data_frame[order(as.Date(data_frame$`Year-Month`,format="%m %Y")),]

Comment: I did not understand what you mean exactly what you mean. so do you want to order dataset after binding all excels together?

Comment: Yes Please. Once the binding is complete. Now that I have data_frame object with column Year_Month. When I try sorting, it returns something like this:
Apr 2023
Apr 2024
Jan 2023
Jan 2024
Mar 2023
Mar 2024

I want:
Jan 2023
Apr 2023
mar 2023
Jan 2024
Apr 2024
mar 2024

Answer (score 0):

Base R approach, staying with `lapply()`; you may start from here.

Approach:

```r
X = format(as.Date(paste0("01", gsub(".*Sample(.*)\\..*", "\\1", files, perl = TRUE)), "%d %B %Y"), "%b %Y")
lapply(seq_len(length(lst_of_frames)), 
       \(i) data.frame(lst_of_frames[[i]], 
                       mon_year = rep(X[[i]], nrow(lst_of_frames[[i]]))))
```

Result:

```r
[[1]]
  a mon_year
1 1  Oct 2023

[[2]]
  b mon_year
1 1  Nov 2023
2 2  Nov 2023

[[3]]
  x mon_year
1 1  Dec 2023
```

Data:

```r
# file_names would have been a more accurate name
files = c("Test Sample October 2023.xlsx",
          "Test Sample November 2023.xlsx", 
          "Test Sample December 2023.xlsx")
lst_of_frames = list(data.frame(a = 1), data.frame(b = c(1, 2)), data.frame(x = 1))
```